# Empty CSV in web scraping - Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to create a CSV for all the tables which appear in each link. [This](http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado/A.html) is the link

In the link there are 36 links, so 36 csv should be generated. When I run my code, 36 csv are created but they are all empty. My code is below:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




first=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado/A.html").read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(first)
w=[]
for q in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for link in q.find_all('a'):
        w.append(link["href"])



l=[]

for t in w:
    l.append(t.replace(".","",1))





def record (part) :


        url="http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado".format(part)
        u=urllib2.urlopen(url)
        try:
            html=u.read()
        finally:
            u.close()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
        c=[]
        for n in soup.find_all('center'):
            for b in n.find_all('a')[2:]:
                c.append(b.text)

        t=(len(c))/2
        part=part[:-6]
        name=part.replace("/","")


        with open('{}.csv'.format(name), 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            for i in range(t):
                url = "http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado{}{}.html".format(part,i)
                u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
                try:
                    html = u.read()
                finally:
                    u.close()
                soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
                for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
                    tds = tr.find_all('td')
                    row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[:6]]
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

With this `for`, I run the created function to create the CSV per link.

```
 for n in l:
        record(n)
```

EDIT: According to the advice of [Alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe), I change the code, and it's working OK just for the fist two links. Moreover, There's a message `HTTP Error 404: Not Found` . I revise in the directory and there are just two csv which are created correctly.

Here's the code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



    def record(part):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado".format(part)))
        c=[]
        for n in soup.find_all('center'):
            for b in n.find_all('a')[1:]:
                c.append(b.text)

        t = (len(links)) / 2
        part = part[:-6]
        name = part.replace("/", "")

        with open('{}.csv'.format(name), 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            for i in range(t):
                url = "http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado{}{}.html".format(part, i)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
                for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
                    tds = tr.find_all('td')
                    row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[:6]]
                    writer.writerow(row)


    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/admisionsabado/A.html"))
    links = [tr.a["href"].replace(".", "", 1) for tr in soup.find_all('tr')]

    for link in links:
        record(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find_all('center')` finds nothing.

Replace:

```
c=[]
for n in soup.find_all('center'):
    for b in n.find_all('a')[2:]:
        c.append(b.text)
```

with:

```
c = [link.text for link in soup.find('table').find_all('a')[2:]]
```

---

Also, you can pass `urllib2.urlopen(url)` directly to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
```

Also, since you have only one link in the row, you can simplify the way you are getting a list of links. Instead of:

```
w=[]
for q in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for link in q.find_all('a'):
        w.append(link["href"])
```

do this:

```
links = [tr.a["href"] for tr in soup.find_all('tr')]
```

Also, pay attention to how you are naming variables and code formatting. See:

- [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- [google python style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)

Comment: I replace 'center with 'tr' but it doesn´t work unfortunately.

Comment: @CreamStat ok, wasn't quite right about the fix - updated the answer, should work.

Comment: In my code, the names are correct. So I guess that the problems starts in with open....

Comment: I´m checking and the result is not the expected. For each link , the csv only have 50 row. See my edit.

Comment: This is a different story and you should have opened a new thread since the initial problem you had is solved.